# deepface for generating embedding for multiple faces in single image

Tags: deepface

i am using deep face library for the face recognition project. in my case, I want to detect multiple faces present in the test image using facenet. when I apply deepface preprocess function i see that it generates only one embedding where as in the given image four faces are present. how can i get respective embeddings for each face?

```
**my code looks:**
import deepface as DeepFace
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from deepface.basemodels import Facenet
import os
from deepface.commons import functions

model = Facenet.loadModel()
target_size = (160, 160)
embedding_size = 128
backends = ['opencv', 'ssd', 'dlib', 'mtcnn', 'retinaface']

target_path = "/home/niveus/PycharmProjects/deepface-elastic-research/deepface/align_img/deep_aku.jpg"
target_img = functions.preprocess_face(target_path, target_size = target_size,detector_backend = backends[3])
target_embedding = model.predict(target_img)[0] #[0]
print(target_embedding.shape)
print("embeddings",target_embedding)
```

Answer (score 2):

Deepface enforces you to use single faces in an image. But you are still able to process multiple faces.

1- Extract faces with retinaface

```
#!pip install retina-face
from retinaface import RetinaFace
faces = RetinaFace.extract_faces(img_path = "img.jpg", align = True)
```

2- Pass extracted faces to deepface

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace

embeddings = []
for face in faces:
   embedding = DeepFace.represent(img_path = face, model_name = 'Facenet', enforce_detection = False)
   embeddings.append(embedding)
```

The trick is to set the enforce detection argument to false because we will pass already detected faces to deepface.

Comment: hey @johncasey thank you so very much. This is really helpful.  I will try with this  trick and update the status here.  .

Comment: `from mtcnn import MTCNN
import cv2
#pass1
img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread("all_faces.jpeg"), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
detector = MTCNN()
faces=detector.detect_faces(img)

faces[0]

#pass2
embeddings = []
for face in faces:
   embedding = DeepFace.represent(face, model_name = 'Facenet', enforce_detection = False)
   embeddings.append(embedding)`

Comment: does not seem to work with MTCNN. once detector is applied to a image it returns metadata and metadata ( that is face object here) is fed as first argument to the represent function gives error saying " TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not dict". kindly correct me if i missed anything. the entire code snippet is below

Comment: I am using retina face to extract images in a loop but i notice that when used in loop, the time it takes to extract faces increases with every image. Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: @RohaanMazoor it builds a neural networks model in the first call. since 2nd call, you just call this neural network to predict. so, you cannot speed it up. only you can do is to invest a powerful hardware. retinaface is very complex model. This is very normal to take time.

Comment: Thanks @johncasey I think you should add this description that DeepFace only work with one face because I'm using extract_faces and apparently is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are also able to use MTCNN instead of RetinaFace. RetinaFace is amazing but it is very slow. Instead, mtcnn comes with high performance and speed.

```
from mtcnn import MTCNN
from deepface import DeepFace
import cv2

img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread("deepface/tests/dataset/img1.jpg"), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
detector = MTCNN()

detections = detector.detect_faces(img)

embeddings = []
for detection in detections:
   confidence = detection["confidence"]
   if confidence > 0.90:
      x, y, w, h = detection["box"]
      detected_face = img[int(y):int(y+h), int(x):int(x+w)]
      
      embedding = DeepFace.represent(detected_face, model_name = 'Facenet', enforce_detection = False)
      embeddings.append(embedding)
```

The both retinaface and mtcnn find facial landmarks such as eyes. In that way, deepface can align faces in the background and it increases the quality of embeddings dramatically. However, opencv is not good at finding landmarks. That's why, if you are going to use opencv, its score might be low because of the alignment.